# How can I avoid google mail server asking me to log in via browser?

Tags: email, gmail, captcha, google-apps

I am trying to send emails from Django using an email configured by Google Apps, my configuration at the `settings.py` file looks something like this:

```
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'contact@mydomain.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'password'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
```

When I try to send an email using:

```
from django.core.mail import send_mail

send_mail("Happy new year", "We wish you the best for 3001",
    "contact@mydomain.com", ["someuser@gmail.com"])
```

I get the following error:

```
SMTPAuthenticationError: 
(535, '5.7.1 Please log in with your web browser and then try again. 
 Learn more at
 5.7.1 https://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?answer=78754 k2sm758604obl.14')
```

Since I'm working on a remote server with no graphical user interface, I cannot even try to login from the browser.

Comment: I'm using exactly the same settings (except for the user/password of course) and it works for me. Are you using a standard Gmail address, or is it a Google apps account with your own domain name? That's the only thing that comes to my mind that could cause this problem. And also make sure that your credentials are correct. That's what the Google help page behind the link tells you to do.

Comment: I'm using a Google apps account with my own domain name. It actually worked on my home computer after a few attempts (and login in using the browser). But I can't make it work from the remote server.

Comment: Have you follow the three google checks posted in your google support link? (UnlockCaptcha)

Comment: When I visit those links from my home computer, they just redirect me to the email account. It seems that I need to visit them from the machine that is having the issue, but I don't have access to a graphical interface on that machine.

Comment: For anyone encountering problems configuring the required HTTP/S tunnel: http://superuser.com/questions/490632/tunneling-https-traffic-via-a-putty-ssl-tunnel-with-socks

Comment: Actual solution http://stackoverflow.com/a/43465118/742173

Answer (score 63):

Just go to 
https://accounts.google.com/DisplayUnlockCaptcha 
and click "continue". This is going to allow access from other servers.

Comment: This worked for me when trying to retrieve mail from a PHP script.

Comment: This also worked for a JIRA server to have access to a google account.

Comment: Whoa - that allowed me to send my gmail python script. thank you!

Comment: this worked for an Ubuntu server to sent a reset password email

Comment: This worked for me when running a node-imap script on digital ocean.

Comment: This worked for me from happy Berkeley, California using Rails on Heroku ☺️

Comment: Still works in 2020. This wins the voodoo magic award

Comment: And it also worked for my Thunderbird not being able to read mail from Google's IMAP

Comment: This worked for me on a Ubuntu vm server, trying to send email from a python script. Thanks!

Comment: Forgot....can someone explain how that url works or what it does. Any documentation?

Answer (score 32):

I've been messing with this for a couple of hours within a cucumber/capybara/selenium test - discovered something stupid which will fix this error for good, guaranteed

The all too familiar error:

```
Please log in via your web browser: https://support.google.com/mail/accounts/answer/78754 (Failure) (Net::IMAP::NoResponseError)
```

As it turns out, **there are TWO "Allow Less Secure Apps" toggles** which need to be changed to allow logins from unknown devices/IMAP.

**One here**: https://myaccount.google.com/security?pli=1#connectedapps (bottom of the page)

**And one here**: https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps

BOTH OF THESE GODFORSAKEN TOGGLES need to be changed to get rid of this error message.

edit: from user Milothicus (https://stackoverflow.com/users/3538026/milothicus): in myaccount.google.com, under 'Sign-in & Security', select 'Connected apps & sites'. this also has an option to 'Allow less secure apps'. after turning this one on, my server could now send me an automated email.

Comment: This was the only one that worked for me when trying to send email from a Perl script on Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: Wow!  Usually Google does good UI, but two identically named toggles... what a screw up!  Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 14):

When I tried to access my account I was sent this email consisting of this link.
https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps

You can turn-on then possibly turn-off after you've done testing.

Answer (score 7):

I got the following response from Google Apps support:

> You need to turn on your Outbound relay. To do this:
>
> 1. Log into your account at google.com/a/yourdomain.com
> 2. Click the Settings tab and then select Email in the left column.
> 3. In the Outbound relay section, select Allow users to send mail through an external SMTP when configuring a "from" address hosted
>      outside your domain.
> 4. Click Save changes.

They also provided a help link: http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=176054

After turning on Outbound relay and using the proxy to login to the webmail one more time (thanks to @DaniloBargen and @joshcartme) the issue was resolved. I've read the link explaining what the Outbound relay is and I'm not really sure why would I need it (I don't believe I'm using an external SMTP server).

Since I'm not really sure this is what solved the issue I won't mark the response as accepted until I get some confirmation.

Comment: This issue started happening to us today, and we have the correct setting checked in Outbound Relay.

Comment: Since you last updated your answer I think the process changed. I had the same error and what I did was log in to my account via the browser, then go to https://accounts.google.com/DisplayUnlockCaptcha (which I accessed from [here](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/14257?hl=en)) and then send an email via Django. Now the client is recognised and I can continue sending mails via that address in Django.

Answer (score 5):

Set up an ssh tunnel to the server in question so that you could, from your home computer, log in to the gmail web client using the server's IP.  You probably need to tunnel port 80 and port 443, maybe just 443.  After logging in through the web client the problem should go away according to knowledge base article listed in the SMTPAuthenticationError.

Here's an example of how to set up the tunnel: 
http://www.noah.org/wiki/SSH_tunnel#simple_port_forwarding_.28SSH_tunneling.29

Comment: An easier way to connect to the other network using tunnels is to use a dynamic tunnel (`ssh -D 6789 remotehost`) and then to set `localhost:6789` as SOCKS5-Proxy in Firefox. Then you are basically in the remote network with your browser and localhost is the remote host.

Comment: I managed to set up the tunnel using @DaniloBargen's method (thanks!). I can actually log in to the email account using the browser but the problem persists. What's really weird is that I tried one of the suggestions of the above link, went to https://www.google.com/a/yourdomain.com/UnlockCaptcha (changing the domain, of course). But none of the username/password combinations worked. I've sent an email to Google Apps support about this.

Comment: I had marked this answer as accepted because, while I'm not exactly sure how I resolved the issue, this answer was a definitely helpful and necessary. It just got unmarked, so I guess someone else knows better. Maybe I should have marked my own response where I explained the situation as accepted?

Comment: The steps are: setup proxy using @DaniloBargen method, clear browser cache or open another browser, login in gmail.

Answer (score 5):

**Option #1 (this worked for me):**

After getting the error `Please log in with your web browser and then try again. Learn more etc.` when trying to send email from my web application, I logged in to the email via browser from my local computer.

After I logged in, there was a yellow notification bar on top which asking me if I want to allow external application access my mail. I confirmed this and Google asked me to log in to the account from the application **within the next 10 mins**. This will white-list the application.

**Option #2:**

If Option #1doesn't work for you, try this: http://www.rocketideas.com/2012/05/gmail-error-password-not-accepted-from-server-solved/

Comment: Option 1 worked for me, thanks. In my case it was a WordPress site using 'Configure SMTP' to send contact emails. Google flagged up the 'suspicious activity' when logging in via the browser, and offered me the opportunity to whitelist the ip/site. Thanks for posting! :)

Answer (score 4):

etusm provided two locations to turn on less secure apps:

> One here: https://myaccount.google.com/security?pli=1#connectedapps
>   (bottom of the page)
>
> And one here: https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps

both were turned on, but my headless server still couldn't send me an email. based on JohnPang's google+ recommendation, i found a third location where i had to allow access to less secure apps:

in myaccount.google.com, under 'Sign-in & Security', select 'Connected apps & sites'. this also has an option to 'Allow less secure apps'. after turning this one on, my server could now send me an automated email.

Comment: Thank you. I missed that third one, but will update accordingly. -Done

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution at: https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833?hl=en and finally https://security.google.com/settings/security/apppasswords

If you are testing your project on a local machine, you should go to the latter link, and enable "Access for less secure apps".

Answer (score 1):

Do you have two factor authentication enabled for the apps account ? Then you might need to use an application specific password for that application.

Answer (score 1):

All of the above doesn't help in my case (weird).  But this link might help you:

https://security.google.com/settings/security/activity

You can access it via Google Plus

1. Open Google+
2. Select "Security" from the top
3. Under "Recent activity" click "View all events"
4. You will see a list of "Unusual Activity"
5. It shows "Application / device sign-in attempt (prevented)    Singapore"  as I'm using AWS from Singapore
6. Click on "Change" > "Yes, that was me!"
7. Retry again.  Done!

Answer (score 0):

As of now (look at my post date) there is only one "Allow less secure apps" toggle in the Gmail account admin UI:
https://myaccount.google.com/u/0/security#connectedapps

It'll work from your **local computer** (Mac or PC) after that.

To allow access from **Amazon EC2** (and I suspect other Cloud-located hosts), there is yet another flag to set in Google's never ending battle with spammers:
https://accounts.google.com/b/0/DisplayUnlockCaptcha

Answer (score 0):

Recently, I have found that this issue can be resolved by confirming that the activity has originated from a request I initiated, by visiting [Google Account](https://myaccount.google.com/)

I had to confirm, under Security Events, that the suspicious activity was in-fact me, even though the originating server from where the request came from was cloud hosted, and therefore over 1000 km away.  After clicking this step, and setting less secure apps, I was able to use getmail to retrieve my mail, over ssl using either imap or pop.

Answer (score 0):

Just want to highlight [Danilo Bargen's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10013736/how-can-i-avoid-google-mail-server-asking-me-to-log-in-via-browser#comment12811360_10016572):

> An easier way to connect to the other network using tunnels is to use a dynamic tunnel (ssh -D 6789 remotehost) and then to set localhost:6789 as SOCKS5-Proxy in Firefox. Then you are basically in the remote network with your browser and localhost is the remote host

Also I want to add that `SOCKS Proxy` method also works with Chrome. As a result you can `log in with your local web browser` as if you are on a server.

Answer (score -1):

change your settings at https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps so that your account is no longer protected by modern security standards.

Answer (score -1):

This is occuring due to some apps are marked as less secure apps by google. So to use those apps, you need to give access for those apps. to do that follow http://www.codematrics.com/your-imap-server-wants-to-alert-you-to-the-following-please-login-via-your-web-browser-gmail/

Hope this will solve your issue.

Answer (score -3):

In my case, when i tried to login to the google account via web, it asked me for a captcha. I entered the captcha and then the automation worked.