# Ubuntu: Sendmail exited with error 70

Tags: linux, email, ubuntu

I am trying to send mail using my gmail smtp server. Currently, I have created several files such as .esmtprc and .muttrc. Well yeah, I am using both esmtp and mutt to configure my mail. Right now, when i try to send an email through the gmail smtp server, i am being shown an error message `Error sending message, child exited 70 (Internal Error.). Could not send message.`.

This is my .esmtprc file:

```
identity " xxx@gmail.com "
hostname smtp.gmail.com:587
username " xxx@gmail.com "
password "password"
starttls required
```

This is my .muttrc file:

```
set sendmail="/usr/bin/esmtp"
set envelope_from=yes
set from="xxx@gmail.com "
set use_from=yes
set edit_headers=yes
```

This is the esmtp.log file

```
S: 220 smtp.gmail.com ESMTP n13sm209293pfj.16 - gsmtp
C: EHLO xxx-HVM-domU
S: 250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [219.92.228.245]
250-SIZE 35882577
250-8BITMIME
250-STARTTLS
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-PIPELINING
250-CHUNKING
250 SMTPUTF8
C: STARTTLS
S: 220 2.0.0 Ready to start TLS
C: EHLO xxx-HVM-domU
S: 250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [219.92.228.245]
250-SIZE 35882577
250-8BITMIME
250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN XOAUTH2 PLAIN-CLIENTTOKEN OAUTHBEARER XOAUTH
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-PIPELINING
250-CHUNKING
250 SMTPUTF8
C: AUTH LOGIN cmFhajU2NzEucmxAZ21haWwuY29t
S: 334 UGFzc3dvcmQ6
C: U2VjcmV0YWdlbnQ0Ng==
S: 454 4.7.0 Cannot authenticate due to temporary system problem. Try again later. n13sm209293pfj.16 - gsmtp
C: AUTH PLAIN [removed]
S: 534-5.7.14 534-5.7.14 n5Us4wZ_BQ7Nif13yL9GGAHgpdUr9vLq0O83X2_n54Ml1C8_lXvz3VpzllkB9XO5spAeXh
534-5.7.14 PmZlB2d75HuJ_7OFxSj5pxHEWtmV4mLMDIQlpRZxqtMj6ySIkKdlQQwfIBWGWKVy9yqNO_
534-5.7.14 liQ7-VCI7WmkngNsrQrIzrTa6__LgxhsxwKB2BwamuvpZuJW2MbicQTRgnJetHOBMpCPhG
534-5.7.14 Mr80WaJpYJuieWXf5H1fGnGSxbGcs> Please log in via your web browser and
534-5.7.14 then try again.
534-5.7.14  Learn more at
534 5.7.14  https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78754 n13sm209293pfj.16 - gsmtp
C: QUIT
S: 221 2.0.0 closing connection n13sm209293pfj.16 - gsmtp
```

These are the main files i have configured before testing the mail function. Can someone help to solve this problem. Thank you.

Comment: So when you turn on verbose logging in esmtp [as shown in the docs](http://esmtp.sourceforge.net/manual.html#interfacing-to-mail-user-agents), what does it tell you?

Comment: No i didnt turn on the verbose logging in the esmtp. I am currently learning on the kernel programming

Comment: So you want help, and more information is easily available, but you aren't going to share it? Good luck with that.

Comment: Not a programming question anyway; voting to close as off-topic.

Comment: @Useless the thing I am trying to say here is I am beginner to Linux so I dont know what does verbose logging means and how to turn it on.

Comment: @tripleee then what question is this. The question is clearly stated about Linux.

Comment: @Useless i have edited the question and add the .esmtp log file which u asked for.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a programming site. Show us a program you wrote and we'll help solve your problem with it. Please review the [help] for details, and post on [meta] if you still have questions about this site's scope or operations. Your question might be suitable for e.g. [su] but do check their posting guidelines before taking it there.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10013736/how-can-i-avoid-google-mail-server-asking-me-to-log-in-via-browser

Comment: Thank you @tripleee

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have solved it by heading Google's [less secure apps](https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps) page. And turn on the less secure apps. Now I can send mail through mutt application.